# Surely this jQuery shouldn't work

Tags: jquery

I have written a piece of code by mistake that works. Now i need it explained to me because its confusing me how its working:

```
$(altsValue[i].css('border', '5px solid red'));
```

'altsValue' is an array of Objects, constructed like this: `altsValue.push($(this));`

'i' is a counter in a loop.

The problem is that the first line is surely one jQuery selector. Yet it does set the CSS of the element in question to the correct property!?

Can someone demystify this for me please?

Comment: That line in general doesn't make sense. Is `altsValue` an extended jQuery object when you call `.push` on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`altsValue[i]` is a jQuery element, since you pushed `$(this)` into it. So it sets the `css` on that element. I don't know what it's doing with the extra `$(...)` around it... probably nothing.

Comment: yup, the extra `$(...)` is essentially a no-op [albet a waste of CPU cycles...].  It's amazing how often you see code where people inadvertently wrap an existing jQuery object into another one!

Comment: Yup. The result of `altsValue[i].css('border', '5px solid red')` will be passed to `$()`, but `altsValue[i].css('border', '5px solid red')` will be run first, hence it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `altsValue.push($(this));` you are pushing jQuery objects into your array.

That means that in your loop, `altsValue[i]` is a jQuery object.

You then call `.css('border', '5px solid red')` on that jQuery object, which sets the border.  Like most jQuery methods, `.css` returns the jQuery object that it operated on.

The outer `$()` is then acting just like `$(altsValue[i])` which is turning an object into another jQuery object.  Since it is already a jQuery object, it just returns the same object.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of your setting properties.
technically you're executing this:

```
var alertsValue = [$(".class#id1"), $(".class#id2")]

altsValue[i].css('border', '5px solid red');
```

As altsValue[i] === $(this); So you're accessing a jQuery object not just an array object.